# Using ENV vars in notification configuration

Tags: travis-ci

I am using travis-ci to test my project Smoke (https://github.com/phmLabs/Smoke). When the test ran I want to report the result to a different system via webhook. The problem is that the webhook url contains a secret key I don't want to put inside my travis.yml file. So I tried using an environment var:

`notifications:
  webhooks: http://monitor.koalamon.com/webhook/travis/?api_key=$KOALAMON_API_KEY`

unfortunateli the environment variable gets escaped and I can see

`127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2016:21:28:25 +0200] "POST /webhook/travis/?api_key=%24KOALAMON_API_KEY HTTP/1.1" 200 278 "-" "Faraday v0.9.2"`

in my apache logs. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I doubt you're able to do that, have you tried firing an issue on GH?

Comment: Talked to @travisci over twitter. They confirmed that it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Alright, cool. Links to tweets?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be using a custom script in the `after_script` section. Those get executed in both fail and success cases of the `script` section. Ofc you'd need a way to re-discover the results of your test.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable is not supported in notifications. There is a bug in github:
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6387

Devs are saying that it is not in their roadmap.